# SQL Server sorting odd numbers ASC and even numbers DESC

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-order-by

I am wondering if there is a way in SQL Server to sort a table which holds numbers in a `varchar` column. I went and cast the number (in my case House Numbers) to `Int` and use

```
order by cast([sano]%2 as int), cast([sano] as Int)
```

which actually creates the output of 2,4,6,8...,1,3,5,7,9 and so on. but I need to get the output like 2,4,6,8..9,7,5,3,1 so even is asc and then the odd is desc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One trick is to use a `case` expression to multiply odd numbers by `-1`, and thus get the ones with the largest absolute value first in an ascending order:

```
ORDER BY CAST([sano] % 2 AS INT), 
         CAST([sano] AS INT) * CASE CAST([sano] % 2 AS INT) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END
```

Comment: i gave this one a try in my db and it works with small nbrs as well as with larger ones like 24600 etc so my follow up question would be how can i list the odd's first and change it from high to low to low to high ?

Comment: @MisterniceGuy you could just add `desc` to both ordering terms

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is a reasonable upper bound on a house number, you can use the following:

```
declare @Samples as Table ( HouseNumber Int );
insert into @Samples ( HouseNumber ) values
  ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 ), ( 4 ), ( 5 ), ( 6 ), ( 7 ), ( 8 ), ( 9 );

select HouseNumber,
  case HouseNumber % 2 when 0 then HouseNumber else 1000000 - HouseNumber end as SortValue
  from @Samples
  order by case HouseNumber % 2 when 0 then HouseNumber else 1000000 - HouseNumber end;
```

For even values it uses the house number. By flipping the sign of odd numbers they are sorted in the opposite order, but an offset is needed to have them sort after the even values.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, but I have no idea why

```
select *
from test
order by CASE WHEN sano%2=0 THEN sano%2 END ASC
```

I am testing and investigating this behaviour

Comment: add `CASE WHEN sano%2=0 THEN sano%2 END` to the select clause and examine the result. It seems to work because you happen to creating the rows in ascending order.

Comment: I saw that already, ok, will keep searching for a real answer that works in any situations